# Use jQuery to load content into DIV and then manipulate select menu options

Tags: jquery

After page load, I am loading a select menu into a DIV like this:

```
$('div#searchform').load('_searchform.asp');
```

That load generates a SELECT menu which displays on the screen. Afterwards, I am trying to select certain options in that list, but the select menu doesn't exist in the DOM. I know how to use ON to assign events to dynamically-loaded content like this, but in this case there is no event. I just want the "select" to happen on page load. My Javascript looks like this:

```
$('option[value="185"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But it doesn't see the menu, so that doesn't work. How can I get my script to see the dynamically-loaded content and manipulate the selected option?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the work in the callback:

```
$('div#searchform').load('_searchform.asp', function() {
    //content loaded, manipulate here
});
```

Comment: I want to put a script to load different option menus on different pages, though. There are other times I have wanted to do something similar, so would love to know a way to load content but make it immediately accessible.

Comment: This is the way to do that @BBDesign -- you need to make use of the callbacks, whether it be doing the work inside an anonymous function (like above) or passing a defined callback function

Answer (score 0):

Use **callback** function of load

```
$('div#searchform').load('_searchform.asp', function() {
    //Peform manipulation here
    $('option[value="185"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Also, Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`